# Solution project reference strategy in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, dll, projects-and-solutions

I have 5 basic projects that need to be part of multiple applications. WinForms, ASP.NET, WPF depending on the needs we have.

These Projects are:

```
Company.Business - Business Logic DLL
Company.Business.Model - Business Models
Company.Business.DAL - Various DALs
Company.Configuration.Classes - Classes that are used to initialize BOs
Company.Utilities - General Utilities
```

Now i am trying to decide how i should go about when i create new UI solutions?

1) Include the projects by `Add->Existing project` ?

2) Copy the compiled .dlls to each solution manually?

In case of option 2 where i should do the basic development for all the above? Probably a separate solution that includes them all? and in there i should start unit testing?

Answer (score 0):

My take on this is that it depends on your needs and how mature the "basic" projects are.

1. Your needs

   - If you need to look at into the code of the "basic" projects while working on the using-projects, then I'd add them to the current solution with the add-existing project method. In situations with multiple added existing projects I make a solution folder called "referenced projects" and add them in this folder.
2. Maturity

   - If your "basic" projects are still being developed (perhaps side-by-side) with the using-projects I'd also would add them in the solution as described above.
   - But if you have no need to look at the code then you might as well include the compiled dll in your client-projects.

Harry